# When does an integral operator belong to the Schatten - von Neumann class in terms of its kernel?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, lp-spaces

It is well known that an integral operator $X: L^2(\mu)\to L^2(\nu)$ with kernel $k(x, y)$ belongs to the Schatten-von Neumann class $\mathfrak S_2$ if and only if 
$\int |k(x, y)|^2\, d\mu(x)\, d\nu(y)<\infty$, that is, the kernel $k$ belongs to $L^2(\mu\times\nu)$. Do there exist necessary or sufficient conditions of the form $k\in L^{p}(\mu\times\nu)$ for the property $X\in\mathfrak S_{p'}$ if $p, p'\ne 2$?

Comment: Google integral operator, Shatten p-class

Comment: @Norbert: did you find anything? I didn't.

Comment: I found that people consider very special cases of this problem, so general problem is unmanageabale

Comment: Ok. I meant only implications in the general form.